# How would SLP997 be calculated on a METAR?

Tags: metar

How would SLP997 be calculated on a METAR? I understand that SLP117 say would be 1011.7 hPa, but I am sure that SLP997 is not 1099.7 as that would be impossibly high.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer to FAA document, AC 00-45H Aviation Weather Services

> 3.1.5.13.25 Sea-Level Pressure.
>
> At designated stations, the sea-level pressure is coded in the
>   following format: the identifier **SLP**,
>   immediately followed by the sea-level pressure in 1 millibars (mb) .
>   The hundreds and thousands units are not coded and must be inferred.
>   For example, a sea-level pressure of 998.2 mb is coded **SLP982**. A
>   sea-level pressure of 1,013.2 mb would be coded **SLP132**. For a
>   METAR, if sea-level pressure is not available, it is coded **SLPNO**.